# how to customize label present on y axis in horizontal bar chart extjs(screenshot inside)

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

[image: if the name of USA becomes too large such as of 48 characters then(eg:usabdhdhdhudhsjsddjbsdbjdhbsbchjcnbscbhjsbshcbhsjchhb)] then the graph shrinks so how can i adjust the width of label text on Y-axis.

Comment: instead of usa if name is changed to 48 characters like (jhqdjbhbjxbhqjhxbhbxwjhqbhjcbjhbchbwqwx) then the graph shrinks.

Comment: I want to customize the display of y-axis text .when it becomes long(48 characters)

Comment: Post some code. You can use a label renderer.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cdq&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`label: {
     rotate: {
          degrees: 300
     }
}`

to skew labels.

Comment: This solution is not my requirement.i just want to customize the size of label text in the y-axis. btw thanks for the help.